# Override property setter abstract method in child class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been exploring the `@property` decorator and abstract classes for the first time and followed along with the Python docs to define the following classes:

```
In [125]: from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
     ...: class C(ABC):
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         self._x = None
     ...:     @property
     ...:     def x(self):
     ...:         """I'm the 'x' property"""
     ...:         return self._x
     ...:     @x.setter
     ...:     @abstractmethod
     ...:     def x(self, value):
     ...:         self._x = value
     ...:     @x.deleter
     ...:     def x(self):
     ...:         del self._x
     ...: class D(C):
     ...:     pass
```

The setter property in class C is an `abstractmethod`. I'm aware that I must override this setter property(method) in class D in order to instantiate an object, but I'm unsure how to do that as all methods in class C are named the same. Now, I know, I could just call the methods `getx()`, `setx()` etc. in class C and just override `setx()` in class D, but I want to know if there's a way to do it with the property syntax above.

Comment: What you're trying to do should be possible in Python 3.3 and up: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty

Comment: okay, yes I figured this in the linked docs, right at the bottom: https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty

Comment: Yeah, IIRC `property.setter` just returns a new copy of the `property` object with its `fset` attribute assigned.

Comment: Yes, I also believe that's how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) show that its possible to override the setter property like this:

```
  ...: class D(C):
  ...:     @C.x.setter #override setter
  ...:     def x(self):
  ...:         pass
```

and now the child class D can be instantiated:

```
In [128]: d = D()
In [129]
```